# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: hibernate

I am not seeing anymore where i am doing my mistake. Working with Spring 3 and Hibernate and Mysql so far worked perfectly and was ok, but on this one it just doesn't work.

This is my class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order")
@XmlRootElement(name = "order")
public class Order implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idOrder", length = 11)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "latitude", nullable = true, length = 45)
    private String latitude;

    @Column(name = "longitude", nullable = true, length = 45)
    private String longitude;

    @Column(name = "orderDate", length = 30)
    @DateTimeFormat
    private Date orderDate;

    @Column(name = "city", nullable = true, length = 45)
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "country", nullable = true, length = 45)
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "street", nullable = true, length = 45)
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "streetNo", nullable = true, length = 45)
    private String streetNo;

    @Column(name = "created", length = 30)
    @DateTimeFormat
    private Date created;

    @JoinColumn(name = "idTaxi")
    @JoinTable(name= "taxi")
    @Column(name = "idTaxi", length = 11)
    private Integer idTaxi;

    @Column(name = "orderstatus", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String orderstatus;

    @Column(name = "clientname", nullable = true, length = 45)
    private String clientName;

    //public getters and setters

}
```

In db, my table name is "order". I have checked all fields for typo.
In persistence xml config file:

```
[...]
 <property name="annotatedClasses">
     <list>
           <value>test.bean.Taxi</value> 
           <value>test.bean.Order</value>
     </list>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        <prop key="lazy">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <!-- Show and print nice SQL on stdout -->  
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>
[...]
```

In DAO class:

```
public List<Order> showAllOpenOrders() {

    List<Order> history = new ArrayList<Order>();
    history = getHibernateTemplate().find("FROM Order o where o.orderstatus ='open'");

    return history;
}
```

My Error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [] in context with path [/] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [select order0_.idOrder as idOrder1_, order0_.city as city1_, order0_.clientname as clientname1_, order0_.country as country1_, order0_.created as created1_, order0_.idTaxi as idTaxi1_, order0_.latitude as latitude1_, order0_.longitude as longitude1_, order0_.orderDate as orderDate1_, order0_.orderstatus as orderst10_1_, order0_.street as street1_, order0_.streetNo as streetNo1_ from order order0_ where order0_.orderstatus='open']; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order order0_ where order0_.orderstatus='open'' at line 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3256)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1313)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1448)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:904)
at test.rest.persistence.OrderDAOImpl.showAllOpenOrders(OrderDAOImpl.java:154)
at test.rest.services.OrderServiceImpl.showAllOpenOrders(OrderServiceImpl.java:109)
at test.rest.controller.OrderController.showAllOrders(OrderController.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have successfully mapped another class(Taxi), but this one..just doesn't work.I don't get why... Do you see something i don't?
So my db table is lowecase "order" and in my Class Order i am mapping that table.
But if I try to access all the records from database with status set on "open" like this:

```
public List<Order> showAllOpenOrders() {
    ;
    List<Order> history = new ArrayList<Order>();
    history = getHibernateTemplate().find("FROM Order o where o.orderstatus ='" + TaxiStatus.OPEN + "'");

    return history;
}
```

I receive an error that there is an SQL Exception.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

order - is reserved keyword in MySQL, and must be `backquoted` if it used not as part of `order by`

rewrite you query as:

```
history = getHibernateTemplate().find("FROM `Order` o where o.orderstatus ='" + TaxiStatus.OPEN + "'");
```

Comment: thank you. such a stupid mistake, i didn't see the problem with the name, even if i knew that order is keyword. Thank you again. it's works.